# can a random number be added to a set..such that its mean and variance will not change

Tags: statistics, mean, variance

i have a set of 4 values. i want to generate a random number which  will be adding to the each of the set. But after adding ,the values of mean and variance should not change.
Meaning mean and variance of set before adding should be same as after adding the number.i was trying to approach it with genetic algorithm .can anyone please  give me more insight on this?

Comment: When you say the "mean and variance should not change", do you mean they should remain exactly the same, or do you mean that they must stay within a certain small distance from the original?

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose your set is called *x*. Let us also suppose that you will add values to *x* to make it *y*. In R, this could be achieved by

```
x <- rnorm(4, mean = 5, sd = 2)
x
[1] 5.124843 3.070105 4.444706 6.657949
rand <- rnorm(0, sd(x))/1000 # Divide by 1000 so rand will have minimum 
                             #impact on the mean and variance of x when added
y    <- x + rand
y
[1] 5.124799 3.066977 4.444524 6.656452
mean(x); mean(y)
[1] 4.824401
[1] 4.823188
```

Now this will show some incremental change but to minimize the incremental change, you can scale `rand` by dividing it by a large number (as I did) or multiplying it by a small number. Another way you can about this is by using the `jitter` function in R. This function uses a small uniform distribution centered about 0 to sample and add noise to data.

```
x <- c(1, -.5, 2, -1.2)
jitter(x)
[1]  1.1117953 -0.5391391  2.0695948 -1.1145638
```

The only downside to `jitter` is that you cannot scale your noise from outside the function. It will scale your entire *x* vector.